# flutter bloc - dispatch event to hosting widget without changing the state

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I got this situation:

- screen1 (widget) navigates to screen2 (widget) and passes it a function (callback)
- screen2 has its own bloc (bloc2)
- screen2 add event to bloc2
- bloc2 performs a long async operation
- when operation completes, bloc2 should notify screen2 (**The problem is here**)
- screen2 should invoke the passed function
- screen1 in a réponse should close screen2

How should bloc2 notify screen2 **without** changing a state.
Changing the state seems a redundant operation in this case, as I don't see a point in build function to run again (and returning a redundant widget)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a BlocBuilder to build screen2, then you could use the `buildWhen` property to determine on which conditions to rebuild, maybe never on state-change?

You can get the blocs public properties and methods using the `previous` and `current` parameters. Those parameters are of type `BlocAState`.

```
BlocBuilder<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  buildWhen: (previous, current) {
    // return true/false to determine whether or not
    // to rebuild the widget with state
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on BlocA's state
  }
)
```

Furthermore, this step:

> screen2 should invoke the passed function

Should, probably, be done in a `BlocListener` or `BlocConsumer`. Maybe that is already how you do it, if not. Look into it..

So to solve your problem I would imagine that you should switch your `BlocBuilder` to a `BlocConsumer`, actually change the state, because your "long async operation" does change the state of screen2 from "not done the long thing", to "has done the long thing". Then your BlocListener can invoke the passed function, and the `buildWhen` property can make sure to not rebuild your screen2.

The `BlocConsumer` looks like this:

```
BlocConsumer<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  listenWhen: (previous, current) {
    // return true/false to determine whether or not
    // to invoke listener with state
  },
  listener: (context, state) {
    // do stuff here based on BlocA's state

    // I.e. invoke the passed function
  },
  buildWhen: (previous, current) {
    // return true/false to determine whether or not
    // to rebuild the widget with state
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    // return widget here based on BlocA's state
  }
)
```